# how to resolve the OLE error 80110802 in HP ALM?

Tags: automated-testing

I have recently started testing and I encountered this problem while performing testing on an application. I use UFT and HP ALM.

Answer (score 1):

While providing software testing solutions we need to go through the various steps before reaching conclusions. Here also got through below mentioned steps to find the cause:

Firstly check whether the COM of API remote agent was registered successfully or not:

1. Open C:\Windows\mercury.ini and enter the below section at end of file

[ExecSchedulerLog]
CreateLog=y
LogFile=C:\QCLogs\Scheduler.log
LogMaxLines=90000

2. Run API test again and check scheduler log, whether it has these line errors

TEVRun_thread.Execute[]: before CreateRemoteComObjectOutProc(host_name,Fclsid);
TEVRun_thread.Execute[]: server_load: raised OLE error 80110802

3. If the error is there its seems that the COM of API Remote Agent was not registered successfully during installation of UFT.
4. Follow below steps to register it manually

- Close ALM client
- Open Command terminal (cmd.exe)
- Enter the command:
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regsvcs.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional Testing\bin\HP.ST.Ext.STRemoteAgent.dll"

The dll should be re-registered successfully and If not, please check whether you have right permissions or not.